# cannot start up service fabric service

Tags: web-services, wcf, azure-service-fabric

While following the tutorial in Programming Azure Service Fabric about creating a WcfCommunicationClient of the calculator service I stumbled upon a problem that I can't find the answer to.

The code is about the same as in the book and the service (WCF) is created like this:

```
    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
  return new[]
  {
    new ServiceInstanceListener(initParams => new WcfCommunicationListener<ICalculatorService>(initParams, this, WcfUtility.CreateTcpListenerBinding(), "ServiceEndpoint"))
  };
}
```

When the service is called the first time, the call hangs forever and the service fabric explorer gives the following error + stacktrace:

> Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.RA', Property='ReplicaOpenStatus',
>   HealthState='Warning', ConsiderWarningAsError=false. Replica had
>   multiple failures during open. Error =System.InvalidOperationException
>   (-2146233079) Poging om contracttype voor ICalculatorService te
>   verkrijgen, maar dat type is geen ServiceContract en neemt ook geen
>   ServiceContract over.    bij
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceReflector.GetContractTypeAndAttribute(Type
>   interfaceType, ServiceContractAttribute& contractAttribute)    bij
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.LoadContractDescriptionHelper(Type
>   contractType, Type serviceType, Object serviceImplementation)    bij
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription.GetContract(Type
>   contractType)    bij
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Wcf.Runtime.WcfCommunicationListener`1.CreateServiceEndpoint(Type
>   contractType, Binding binding, EndpointAddress address)    bij
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Wcf.Runtime.WcfCommunicationListener`1..ctor(ServiceContext
>   serviceContext, TServiceContract wcfServiceObject, Binding
>   listenerBinding, EndpointAddress address, String endpointResourceName)
>   bij
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Wcf.Runtime.WcfCommunicationListener`1..ctor(ServiceContext
>   serviceContext, TServiceContract wcfServiceObject, Binding
>   listenerBinding, String endpointResourceName)    bij
>   CalculatorService.CalculatorService.b__3_0(StatelessServiceContext
>   initParams) in C:\Users\servel\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\CalculatorApplication\CalculatorService\CalculatorService.cs:regel
>   45    bij
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatelessServiceInstanceAdapter.d__10.MoveNext()
>   bij
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    bij
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    bij
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatelessServiceInstanceAdapter.d__0.MoveNext()

Apparently the service cant be started. So what to do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your service implements an interface with WCF `ServiceContract` and `OperationContract` attributes. Like this example [here](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.WcfCalc/blob/master/CalculatorService/ICalculatorService.cs).

Comment: hahaha with all the new info I forgot to add [ServiceContract] to the interface. thanks!